# sync between sq-lite and parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have class in parse.com, this class has books information like ISBN, book name and so on. I have figured out how to receive it from parse, what I would like to know is how can I [syn] between parse and local db or sq-lite, in other words I would like to know how to  get the books information from [#parse] and save them to my app local db, also I would like to know on how I can make my app access my parse class only when there are new book info and update my list for that book.

Comment: What is your platform iOS or Android ? Have you read the documentation on Local datastore and Pinning objects ??

Comment: my platform is android!